Why is my edge-wear shader scale dependent?

I apologize for the color scheme but it was quick and effective for the stack. I usually use a color ramp to control things like gradient intensity and distance but this node setup is different. All these faces share the same shader yet some of them look wrong. Without getting too wordy about what's wrong with it, it just doesn't look evenly distributed - the edge-wear. Link to blend here:Blend file
